# Errors creating a new database with Doctrine orm symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

i tried creating a new data base using the command:

```
$ bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

and I got the following errors:

> In ExceptionConverter.php line 91: An exception occurred in the
> driver: could not find driver
> In Exception.php line 26: could not find driver
>
> In Driver.php line 28: could not find driver

also i tried modifying the database url from:

```
# DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=5.7"
```

to

```
# DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/SMF?serverVersion=5.7"
```

I'm using xampp server.

Comment: If it was a database permission issue then you would get a completely different error message.  The fact that your posted configuration still includes the # sign (which means the line is commented out and therefor ignored) makes me suspect you are getting a error suggesting that the postgres driver is not installed.  If so then uncomment the mysql line.  If the driver error was about mysql then you need to install the pdo_mysql driver.  Which you probably already have if you are using xampp.

Comment: you have to uncomment 
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/SMF?serverVersion=5.7"
and comment (with # ) 
the default databse config example : 
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://symfony:ChangeMe@127.0.0.1:5432/app?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure You have installed all drivers in that machine.
As far as I remember it is: *php-pdo* and *php-pdo_mysql* - depending on Your OS.
You need to have a mysql client to make such database.

Basically run this command in Your console:

```
symfony check:requirements
```

It will show You what package You are missing to run a Symfony app.
Don't forget to match your MySQL Server version with DNS:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/SMF?serverVersion=X.Y"
```

And lastly, [Ouss Ma L'aire Bien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14003393/ouss-ma-laire-bien) mentions, uncomment the DATABASE_URL You want to use and comment out all others.

Comment: now i have uncommented the line # DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/SMF?serverVersion=5.7" and it worked ,thanks for your help, the problem is SOLVED

Comment: Please mark it as solved by accepting this solution. It will help others. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

in your case you should delete the "#"
and if there are other lines staring with DATABASE_URL in your .env file just put "#" in the begining
in other cases, just try your windows cmd